# Can't drupal_execute('filter_admin_format_form') on hook_install?

Tags: 6, installation

I'm attempting to configure an input format on hook_install() with the following code:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'filter', 'filter.admin');
$form_state = array(
  'values' => array(
    'name' => 'Full HTML',
    'format' => '2',
    'roles' => array(
      1 => 0,
      2 => 0,
      3 => 1,
    ),
  ),
);
$arg = filter_format_load(2);
drupal_execute('filter_admin_format_form', $form_state, $arg);
```

However this produces the error:

```
Filter format names need to be unique. A format named Full HTML already exists.
```

However if I run the same code on hook_init(), then it runs without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute that code, but you need to give a unique name for the input format being saved.

As alternative, if you want to be sure there is an input format called *Full HTML*, you can save the input format in the database using db_query(), and using the code of [filter_admin_format_form_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!filter!filter.admin.inc/function/filter_admin_format_form_submit/6), the form submission hander for the form you are executing, as guideline.
The involved database tables are two: filter_formats, and filter_formats; the first contains the data about the input format, and the latter contains the data about the input filters associated with an input format. The relevant executed queries are the following ones.

```
  if (!$format) {
    $new = TRUE;
    db_query("INSERT INTO {filter_formats} (name) VALUES ('%s')", $name);
    $format = db_result(db_query("SELECT MAX(format) AS format FROM {filter_formats}"));
    drupal_set_message(t('Added input format %format.', array('%format' => $name)));
  }
```

```
db_query("DELETE FROM {filters} WHERE format = %d", $format);
```

```
  foreach ($form_state['values']['filters'] as $id => $checked) {
    if ($checked) {
      list($module, $delta) = explode('/', $id);
      // Add new filters to the bottom.
      $weight = isset($current[$id]->weight) ? $current[$id]->weight : 10;
      db_query("INSERT INTO {filters} (format, module, delta, weight) VALUES (%d, '%s', %d, %d)", $format, $module, $delta, $weight);

      // Check if there are any 'no cache' filters.
      $cache &= !module_invoke($module, 'filter', 'no cache', $delta);
    }
  }
```

In Drupal 7, it would be easier, as you can call [filter_format_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!filter!filter.module/function/filter_format_save/7), which always save the input format passed as argument, and eventually merge the format you passed as argument with the existing one.

The function that shows the error you are noticing is the form validation handler,  [filter_admin_format_form_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21filter%21filter.admin.inc/function/filter_admin_format_form_validate/6), which contains the following code.

```
if ($result) {
  form_set_error('name', t('Filter format names need to be unique. A format named %name already exists.', array('%name' => $name)));
}
```

As the form validation handlers, and the form submission handlers are executed when you call [drupal_execute()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_execute/6), the same error is returned, even when `drupal_execute('filter_admin_format_form', $form_state, $arg)` is called from `hook_init()`; it just happens that the error message shown with [form_set_error()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/6) is not immediately visible when `hook_init()` is invoked, but the input format is not saved. 
To notice that `filter_admin_format_form_submit()` executes the following code.

```
  $format = isset($form_state['values']['format']) ? $form_state['values']['format'] : NULL;
  $current = filter_list_format($format);
  $name = trim($form_state['values']['name']);
  $cache = TRUE;

  // Add a new filter format.
  if (!$format) {
    $new = TRUE;
    db_query("INSERT INTO {filter_formats} (name) VALUES ('%s')", $name);
    $format = db_result(db_query("SELECT MAX(format) AS format FROM {filter_formats}"));
    drupal_set_message(t('Added input format %format.', array('%format' => $name)));
  }
  else {
    drupal_set_message(t('The input format settings have been updated.'));
  }
```

Supposing that the form validation handler doesn't return an error, the form submission handler is not saving any data in the "filter_formats" table, if the input format is not new; in such case, the function executes the `else` part of the control statement, which just output a message.

Comment: When I run it with hook_init, I get a successful form submission drupal_set_message on every page load, and the settings save perfectly. However my OCD is going to have to take a backseat as I've decided as you suggest to go the db_query route. Thanks!

Comment: I found an explanation for the message about the settings being updated.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation! I'm still feeling frustrated about why my code wasn't working though. I'm clearly setting $form_state['values']['format'], so why it fails isset() is a mystery to me :S.